Feasibility of converting TiO₂ on titanium to BaTiO₃ in solution
I’m exploring the feasibility of transforming a TiO₂ layer (of varying thickness) on a titanium surface into BaTiO₃ stable layer by processing it in barium-ion-rich solutions. A specific reaction I’ve considered is using a BaCl₂ solution in water, where the interaction could potentially follow this pathway (with additional heat treatment or annealing afterwards):
$\text{TiO}_2 + \text{BaCl}_2 + \text{H}_2\text{O} \rightarrow \text{BaTiO}_3 + 2\text{HCl}$
I’m curious about how effective and efficient this transformation could be, especially for thin vs. thick $\text{TiO}_2$ layers and if it is actually possible.
Are there any known challenges or practical limitations to this method? For example, is the reaction kinetically slow, or does it require precise conditions (e.g., high temperature or ph control) to fully convert $\text{TiO}_2$ into $\text{BaTiO}_3$? Any insights, references, or suggestions for this process would be greatly appreciated!

Updated:
Probably better to use $\text{Ba(OH)}_2$ though:
$\text{TiO}_2 + \text{Ba(OH)}_2 \rightarrow \text{BaTiO}_3$

Your 1st idea is unfeasible. 2nd looks better, but logical step would be breaking up TiO2 before any reaction with Ba compound.

@Mithoron It is critical to perform transformation in-place.

May be this article would help.
